# How to use a variable in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a variable in a string. I have searched for this and tried throwing different things at it but nothing seems to work..

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
http:localhost:8080/Editor/?name=Default
```

I have no issue getting the value using:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var vars = query.split("&");
                for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    if (pair[0] == variable) { return pair[1]; }
                }
                return (false);
            }

            var name = getQueryVariable("name")
```

Now I have a string that loads a page that looks like this:

```
 HMI.Builder.init('Files/HMIBuilder/', function () {
                //run code after page/iframe is loaded
            });
```

What I want to do is add the variable to the string Files/HMIBuilder/{name}
This does not work. It needs to end up looking like this

```
Files/HMIBuilder/Default
```

Or whatever variable is passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate your string with the variable using the javascript `+` symbol, like below:

```
HMI.Builder.init('Files/HMIBuilder/' + getQueryVariable("name"), function () {
  //run code after page/iframe is loaded
});
```

Or use the handy `replace` for more readability:

```
HMI.Builder.init('Files/HMIBuilder/{name}'.replace('{name}', getQueryVariable("name")), function () {
  //run code after page/iframe is loaded
});
```

Of course, you could do it with two steps for even more readability:

```
var route = 'Files/HMIBuilder/{name}'.replace('{name}', getQueryVariable("name"));
HMI.Builder.init(route, function () {
  //run code after page/iframe is loaded
});
```

Finally, on recent browsers (and with some transpilers for backward compatibility), you could use the ES6 "`" syntax:

```
var route = `Files/HMIBuilder/${getQueryVariable("name")}`;
HMI.Builder.init(route, function () {
  //run code after page/iframe is loaded
});
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you. I used the 3rd option. There is a second part to this I may be throwing that up as a question as well..

Comment: So should i be using the 4th option? I want to use what is most current. If this is the format that is being used and up to date then i should use that.. I cant pot my other question yet because it says i have to wait 90 min... Newbie rules i guess...

Comment: There is no « most current » option, it’s really a matter of taste and coding standards on your projects. Personally, I prefer 3rd and 4th choices ;)

Answer (score 2):

use a template literal

```
HMI.Builder.init(`Files/HMIBuilder/${getQueryVariable(variable)}`, function () {

            //run code after page/iframe is loaded
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of parameters by running the following function

```
function extractParams(url) {
    new URL(url).search.substr(1).split('&').map(x => {
        var y = x.split('=');
        return { [y[0]]: y[1] };
    });
}

var params = extractParams('https://www.website.com?id=151&name=john');
```

Which would print the following

`[{id: 151}, {name: "john"}]`