# How to read directory and get an array of all HTML files

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

This is a second part to the question I asked earlier found here:
[How to use a variable in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612694/how-to-use-a-variable-in-a-string)

Now that I have a directory I can use I need to find all the HTML files in that directory and use an array in the current format..

```
HMI.FileManager.addPages(
[
    { name: "Default", title: "Starter Page", url: "Files/HMIBuilder/Default/index.html" },
]);
```

This format automatically loads all the pages that are added to this. So by doing a search in the current directory and then doing an array it should produce all the pages in that directory.

I already have a variable in the string to the directory, is there a way to use that to get to the directory and search it for .html files and then load an array of those files or maybe a `foreach`?

This does not work but is something maybe to work with..

```
htmlFiles = global("*.html")
foreach (htmlFiles as file) {
 path == path(file)
 {name: "path['filename']", title: "path['filename']", url: "path['basename']"},

 }
```

EDIT:
I have added this and it seems that will work for what i need to do. However it is giving me an error that the label is not defined..

```
 @{ 
    var files = Request.QueryString["name"];
    string[] filePaths Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/HMIBuilder/"), files);

           foreach (string name in filePaths)
           {
              { name: name, title: name, url: filePaths },
           }
   }
```

Edit-- 
Changed the above code to be the below. I am now getting an error over the variables that says 'name' is a variable but used like a type... while the filePaths variable is fine.. I'm confused.

```
@{ 
   var files = Request.QueryString["name"];
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/HMIBuilder/"), files);

    foreach (string name in filePaths) {

       @:{ name: @{name}, title: @{name}, url: @{filePaths} },

     }

 }
```

Edit:

After much throwing code at this i finally got this to work. Below is what the final code looks like.

```
  @{
     var files = Request.QueryString["name"];
     var path = ("/Files/HMIBuilder/");
     var fullpath = Path.Combine(path, files);
     DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(fullpath));
     FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.html");

     foreach (FileInfo name in Files) {


         @:{ name: "@name", title: "@name", url: "@fullpath/@name" },

     }
  }
```

Comment: what programming language or platform are you using?

Comment: This is a $(document).ready(function () { } in a razor page using MVC. It might be important to add that this is a Virtual directory..

Comment: Wbat is `HMI.FileManager` ? If you're using some sort of plugin you really need to make clear what it is, then we can understand the context.

Comment: There is not any plugin the Editor is done in 99% javascript. The only thing that is not is what i have added to get to the proper directory. I will post what is pulling the list of files in the tree. However it really doesn't matter because as long as i give the Javascript what it wants to see it will work. In other words if i hardcode the string like it is up top it will show the file in the tree. I just need to get those files without hard coding them..From what i can see from the code it gets the directory, currently, from the hard coded string. I now have that in the url string.

Comment: To add to the last question HMI.FileManger is a javascript function that displays the tree. As long as it gets the 3 labels then it will produce the tree. name is what it calls the file, title is what is shown in the tree and Url is used to click the file to open it in the editor..

Comment: without looking at your full code, this will throw a compiler error.

Comment: You can try this:

@{ 
    var files = Request.QueryString["name"];
    string[] filePaths Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/HMIBuilder/"), files);

           foreach (string name in filePaths)
           {
              @(name)
           }
   }


Now you have to figure out how to get it into javascript.

Comment: @manit I have updated the code above, probably when you were posting this. I am having an issue with name. kinda strange to me but it says i am using it like a type.. now i have noticed that the second place it appears it is telling me is declared but never used. So am i not allowed to use it more than once in a string?